credentials for the registry
Golang package has a type
type CreateOptions struct {     RegistryAuth string // RegistryAuth is the base64 encoded credentials for the registry.     Platform     string // Platform is the target platform of the image if it needs to be pulled from the registry. }

I have sonatype/nexus registry
How credentials look like? json? whan the format?
I tried use docker .docker/config.json file with
{"auths": {"localhost:8082": {"auth": ""}}}


I'm unfamiliar with Sonatype/Nexus registry but all container registries implement the Docker Registry API  and so behave similarly.
The auth value for a specific entry (e.g. localhost:8082) in .docker/config.json represents the base64-encoded credentials i.e. RegistryAuth.
You can confirm this by using the value from the auth property and:
echo "${value}" | base64-decode

And you should receive something of the form:
{username}:{password}

You can recreate this value with:
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"

    "github.com/moby/moby/api/types/registry"
)

func main() {
    authConfig := registry.AuthConfig{
        Username: os.Getenv("USERNAME"),
        Password: os.Getenv("PASSWORD"),
    }

    auth, err := registry.EncodeAuthConfig(authConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("%+s", auth)
}


NOTE The value {PASSWORD} can be a token too issued by the provider in which case there's usually an accompanying {USERNAME} value.


NOTE AuthConfig also includes an Auth field but I'm unsure what purpose this serves.

